# Replace NA values by "-" in R

Tags: r

How do I replace `NA` values by `-` in my code below:

```
library(dplyr)

output<-structure(list(date = structure(c(18808, 18810), class = "Date"), 
               ABC = c(4, 1), CDE = c(1, NA), FGH = c(6, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                             -2L), class = "data.frame")
output<-output %>% mutate(SUM = rowSums(across(2:last_col()), na.rm = TRUE))

> output
        date ABC CDE FGH SUM
1 2021-06-30   4   1   6  11
2 2021-07-02   1  NA  NA   1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `base R`, we may do

```
output[is.na(output)] <- "-"
```

-output

```
> output
        date ABC CDE FGH SUM
1 2021-06-30   4   1   6  11
2 2021-07-02   1   -   -   1
```

Comment: Thanks! For this case it worked, another example when I do this it gives the following error:
`Error: Assigned data "-" must be compatible with existing data.
i Error occurred for column 
x Can't convert <character> to <double>.
Run rlang::last_error() to see where the error occurred.` Do you know how to adjust this?

Comment: @CarlosJoseph It will have a problem in case of tidyverse functions.  But, here we are using just `base R` and it does automatically change the type though

Comment: @CarlosJoseph Can you show an example where this doesn't work

Comment: @CarlosJoseph can you tell me what was the issue

Answer (score 2):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
output %>% mutate(SUM = rowSums(across(2:last_col()), na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~ replace_na(as.character(.), '-')))
        date ABC CDE FGH SUM
1 2021-06-30   4   1   6  11
2 2021-07-02   1   -   -   1
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to eventually run the data.frame through knitr::kable() to get a formatted table, you can add this line to your script:

> options(knitr.kable.NA = "--")

Then, the formatted table (html, pdf, etc) will have long dashes instead of NAs, but the underlying data.frame will not be modified.